# Loading Browser Specific Style Sheets in Modern Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, stylesheet

I really need some help here.  I have searched the forum and the internet for hours.  I have found many articles but they either have no definitive working answers on how to do this or they are too old.

I have 2 stylesheets.  One for IE and one for all other browsers.  This is not ideal I know but this was a complicated project and it is the way things developed.  One sheet is 3D (webkit) and the other is 2D (IE).  I need to be able to load the CSS based on the browser.  I only need the 2 options, IE an other.

I have tried conditional statements and I have tried browser detection.  Must work for modern browsers.

I have tried the following in the head and nothing has worked.  The webkit CSS either overrides the IE CSS or it doesn't load at all.  Please assist.

Attempt 1 (problem - webkit css overrides IE CSS even though it is commented):

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->   

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/SolarWebkit.css" />

<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->   

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/SolarIE.css" />

<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 9]><!-->   

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/SolarIE.css" />

<!--<![endif]-->
```

Attempt 2 (problem - won't load at all in any browser):

```
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
var browserName  = navigator.appName;
var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

// In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Opera";
}
// In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
}
// In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Chrome";
}
// In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Safari";
}
// In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Firefox";
}
// In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent 
else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) < 
          (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) ) 
{
 browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);
 if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
  browserName = navigator.appName;
 }
}

 if (browserName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
 document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/SolarIE.css">");
 }
 else {
 document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/SolarWebkit.css">");
 }
```

I made other attempts but these seemed like the most valid.  Any working solutions are welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Conditional comments don’t work any more in IE >= 10 in standards mode …

Comment: Hi @CBroe.  The <!--[if gte IE 9]><!--> and <!--[if lte IE 9]><!--> seems to work in IE 10.  But when I try to exclude css (Not IE) with the same commenting style it does not work.  Do you have any suggestions that will work?

Comment: User server-side UA string sniffing. There are libraries available to to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

#### Server-side detection

Depending on the server serving the CSS files, you may configure/customize it to serve the file you want depending on the `User-Agent` header.

#### Link to CSS depending on the browser

[See answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344185/2191722) from scunliffe

#### Single CSS with class on body and overridden rules

Detect the browser, and add a class on the body according to the browser, for example `document.body.className += " msie"`

Then override the rules you want in your css

```
body.msie someTag { /*msie specific rules*/ }
```

---

I recommend to use a library for browser detection, they are usually more tested. I just found [WhichBrowser](http://whichbrowser.net/) which seems to do that very well.

Comment: I seem to be having a user agent problem here and I think that is why I can't get it to load for me in JSBIN.  I have visited several sites I.e. Whats my user agent and it is showing as Mozilla even though I am using IE 11.  What can I go here?  Because both the server side and client side scripting that I have found for this require user agent.

Comment: I found most of the solution.  IE11 was causing most of the problem.  I could not use Gecko or rv because that confused the webkit browsers.  With IE11 in the mix I had to use Trident.  IE really shouldn't have started identifying as a webkit until all of the transitions and all of the 3D actually worked in IE.  I updated the JSBIN http://jsbin.com/diquy/1/edit.  The problem now is the script itself won't fire in Chrome.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Can you render the 2D page by default, but redirect to the 3D page if you detect (via feature detection) that the incoming browser supports what you are trying to do?

e.g.

```
<script>
  if(typeof(navigator.fancyNewThing) == 'function'){
    location.href = '3Dpage.html';
  }
</script>
```

or load your CSS accordingly.

Your browser detection code (above in the question) is a bit of overkill.  Though singling out a browser by its user agent isn't always the wisest thing to do, this script should identify IE for you.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1){
  document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/SolarIE.css\">");
} else {
  document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/SolarWebkit.css\">");
}
```

Comment: Hi @scunliffe! In this case no because it is a custom art piece designed to go into an IFrame in an online builder platform so I don't have access the full page css or html.

Comment: Inside an iframe, you page is largely independent from its surroundings – so what exactly do you think you can’t do there …?

Comment: Hi @CBroe that response was about doing a page redirect based on the browser.  What I am trying to do is load it dynamically in the Iframe.

Comment: @scunliffe I set up the second script you provided in JSBin in IE and for some reason IE is defaulting to the webkit css which is the problem I was having before.  Here is the link http://jsbin.com/diquy/1/edit

Comment: @scunliffe I seem to be having a user agent problem here and I think that is why I can't get it to load for me in JSBIN.  I have visited several sites I.e. Whats my user agent and it is showing as Mozilla even though I am using IE 11.  What can I go here?  Because both the server side and client side scripting that I have found for this require user agent.

Comment: Yup that's the problem.  MS made user agent changes to IE 11.  IE 11 returns "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv 11.0) like Gecko".  Found it in this article.  http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/02/internet-explorer-11-dont-call-me-ie/

Comment: @scunliffe I found most of the solution.  IE11 was causing most of the problem.  I could not use Gecko or rv because that confused the webkit browsers.  With IE11 in the mix I had to use Trident.  IE really shouldn't have started identifying as a webkit until all of the transitions and all of the 3D actually worked in IE.  I updated the JSBIN http://jsbin.com/diquy/1/edit.  The problem now is the script itself won't fire in Chrome.  Any ideas?

Comment: Found the answer and posted it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With some great suggestions from the users here I was able to get this right! IE11 was the culprit here.  MS prematurely defined IE11 as a webkit browser so certain properties like the user agent have been updated.  Here's an article on that.  http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/02/internet-explorer-11-dont-call-me-ie/

So MSIE or RV weren't working because it confused the webkit browsers.  I used Trident instead.

The following script works for dynamically loading CSS in the most recent versions of all browsers on the client side:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident') != -1){
  document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/SolarIE.css\">");
  } 


  else {
  document.write("<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/SolarWebkit.css\">");

}

</script>
```